# Using prepared statements for Procedural style

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently getting used to mysqli and am trying to convert a code I have written in mysql. I am using Procedural style to convert the code, however I realise that in mysqli you can use prepared statements, rather than using mysqli_real_escape_string. I have tried to understand these prepared statements, however I cannot get my head around them. How can I convert the below code to prepared statements?

```
function user_exists($email){ 
$query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT `mem_id` FROM `members` WHERE `mem_email`='$email'"); 
$query_result = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
return $query_result; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function user_exists($email){ 
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT `mem_id` FROM `members` WHERE `mem_email`=?"); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $query_result=mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    return $query_result; 
}
```

Seriously, use OOP style would be better...

```
function user_exists($email){ 
    global $___mysqli_ston;//just follow your style
    $stmt = $___mysqli_ston->prepare("SELECT `mem_id` FROM `members` WHERE `mem_email`=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $query_result=$stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->free_result();
    return $query_result; 
}
```

Comment: Using OOP would mean having to change my connection, correct? I can't use a mixture of OOP and Procedural? It's a pain because I have virtually finished the conversion using Procedural

Comment: @user1064811 I provided a procedure style. And guessing from [official doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) and [several method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), `mysqli_connect` returns the same thing as `new mysqli()` (unless there's an error), so I think you can mix both.